# get first word in java script websockets

Tags: javascript, string, websocket, substring

I am currently using websockets in java script and would like to do some string manipulation on the message I receive from the other end of the websocket. I would like to strip off all characters but the first word in a message. For example if I get the message `lets go to the party` I would like to manipulate the string to `lets`. I am thinking that I would go through the string index my index until I hit the first white space. But am not sure about the syntax for that in javascript. Does that sound about right or is there a better way to do it? Sorry if this is trivial I am quite new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
var theMessage = 'Hello world!';
var theFirstWord = theMessage.split(' ')[0]; // 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

A more conservative approach that does not need to create an array of strings, and it does not need to go through the whole string always.

```
function getNthWord(input,wordNumber){

    if(!input || !input.length)
        throw new Exception("No input");
    if(!wordNumber || wordNumber <0)
        throw new Exception ("Word number missing");

    var wordStart=0;
    for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        var c = input[i];
        if(c==' '){
            wordNumber--;
            if(wordNumber==0)
                return input.substring(wordStart,i);
            else
                wordStart=i+1;
        }
    }
    return input.substring(wordStart,input.length);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/7bf2mfag/

I would say it runs in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space, although it may be close to `O(1)` time if the `wordNumber` parameter is small?

On the other hand, using split is always `O(n)` time an space.